# Show Entire Function has Real Coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an entire function with power series $f(z) = \sum^{ \infty}_{n=0} \alpha_{n} z^{n}$. Show that $ \alpha_{n}$ is real for all $n$ if and only if $f(x)$ is real whenever $x$ is real.

I really do not know where to start with this problem.

Comment: $a_0 = f(0), a_1 = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h},a_2 = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(-h)-2f(0)+f(h)}{h^2}$, etc.

Comment: How are you calculating these coefficients? I thought the coefficients were of the form of Derivative of Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Comment: well you should go back to the very definition of an analytic function and its Taylor series...

Comment: I see now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha_n$ are real for all $n$ then it is clear that $f$ must be real for real $z$.

Now suppose $f$ is real for real $z$. Then it is clear that $f'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} {f(z+h)-f(z) \over h} $ is also real for real $z$. It follows that $f^{(k)}(z)$ is real for real $z$. Hence $\alpha_n = {1 \over n!} f^{(n)}(0)$
is real.

Comment: I see, so you are calculating the coefficients of the Taylor Expansion?

Comment: Yes, note that $f(0) = \alpha_0, f'(0) = \alpha_1$, etc.

Comment: +1 ... It might be worth noting that since $f$ is analytic, we may choose to take $h$ as real as it approaches $0$.

Comment: @James.Welch: My last comment (since deleted) was just plain wrong.

Comment: Nice catch, definitely need to note that $h$ is real

Comment: That is ok, at least gave an idea to think about.

Comment: Another approach is to consider $g(z) = \sum_n (\alpha_n-\overline{\alpha}_n) z^n$. Then $g$ is entire and is zero on the real line, hence $g=0$ and hence the coefficients of $z^n$ are all zero, hence $\alpha_n = \overline{\alpha}_n$.

Comment: I like the work hence.

Comment: Nice idea, now I have plenty of hints to think about. Thanks for your help.